# How to check if list has more then 3 elements using Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method that accepts a list of object.

I want to iterate through that list and check if the list has more than 3 elements. If it does, I want to throw error *`You can only add 3 elements`*

If not, I want to save those elements in database.

I want to use Java 8 streams in this case.

So far I have this code:

```
public List<MyObject> addMyObject(List<MyObject> myObject) {

    if (playingStyle.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("object cannot be null");
    }

    return myObject.stream()
        .limit(3)
        .map( ps -> {
            try {
                return repository.save(new MyObject(
                    ps.getName(), ps.getAverage(), ps.getPriority()
                ));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn("MyObject fields not correct {} {}", ps, e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I have tried to use `.limit()` but what it does is it takes first 3 objects (if I have sent in 4) and saves them, last one just forgets.

What I am trying to achieve is if list is empty return error, if list size is bigger than 3 return error, but using Java 8.

Comment: What’s wrong with list.size() > 3 ?

Comment: Why do you create a `new MyObject()` when you save?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez there is nothing wrong, but I am trying to see how to do it with Java 8 :)

Comment: @Kayaman yes, maybe I shouldn't. Thank you!

Comment: @user9347049 in Java 8 you'd do it in the same way you'd do it with Java 1.0 :) . This is in no way a good use case for streams, streams are for processing a (potentially) large number of elements in a lazy way, doing some operations on each one and/or accumulating them; going through all the overhead of using streams instead of using an `O(1)` operation such as `size()` that has the same effect, is quite an overkill...

Comment: @ÓscarLópez thank you for your answer. As right now I am trying to learn how to use more efficiently in my code functional programming approach, Java 8... guess I sometimes just overkill it then... well maybe you are right. But I just wanted to see is there a way to do it in stream.

Comment: Going stream in yours case not advisable. Go with list.size() >3

Comment: @ÓscarLópez well, it’s like in JDK 1.2, actually.

Answer (score 1):

For a `List` just check the `size` property.

For a `Stream`, you can do:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Main {
    
    private static Boolean hasThreeOrMoreElements(final Stream s) {
        return s.limit(3).count() >= 3;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hasThreeOrMoreElements(Arrays.asList(1).stream()));
        System.out.println(hasThreeOrMoreElements(Arrays.asList(1, 2).stream()));
        System.out.println(hasThreeOrMoreElements(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream()));
        System.out.println(hasThreeOrMoreElements(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).stream()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public List < MyObject > addMyObject(List < MyObject > myObject) {

    if (playingStyle.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("playingStyle cannot be null");
    }

    if (myObject.size() > 3)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can only add 3 elements");

    return myObject.stream()
        .map(ps -> {
            try {
                return repository.save(new MyObject(ps.getName(), ps.getAverage(), ps.getPriority()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn("MyObject fields not correct {} {}", ps, e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Also, I would change `repository.save(new MyObject(ps.getName(), ps.getAverage(), ps.getPriority()));` to `repository.save(ps);`

Comment: Is it possible to check if list is empty and for size that is less than 3 within stream?

Comment: @user9347049 A stream operates on an existing list, not validates its properties. What do you have against checking the conditions beforehand?